# Can we interpret Frankenstein as a work by an author struggling with depression?

Tags: interpretation, mary-shelley, frankenstein

There's no "My God, man, you're not telling us something!" moment, is there? Victor's family sort of sit by as they're all killed off and even his dad doesn't press him.

I know we're supposed to judge spoiled Victor against the man who lives in a hovel and splits your firewood, but it implies family and friends are more aloof than they are, right? This sounds like what a woman who lived with  depression for most of her life would probably write.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. This is an interesting question but the last sentence may come across as rather speculative. If you reworded it as "Can *Frankenstein* be interpreted as expressing a depression as a worldview?", it may be safer. (See [this search query](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=depression+%22world+view%22&ia=web) for articles etc on depression as a worldview.)

Comment: @Tsundoku Maybe depression is the wrong word? I mean it as a mental disorder, not a worldview.

Comment: Hi Ethan, did you check any of the resources from the search query in my previous comment? Several of those point out that depression is also a worldview. If you exclude the wordview aspect and focus exclusively on the mental disorder aspect, I'm not sure your question will be answerable.

Comment: I'm not sure I see an answerable question here. *Can* we? Sure we can. What stops anybody from so doing?

Comment: There is clarification required of the statments following the question : they are vague and it is unclear what relation they bear to the original question . What i meant by the first statement ( 'There...him ) ? and why do we know where supposed to judge spoiled victor and what has this to do with the question being asked ? I fail to see how the final sentence follows from the previous statments .Please clarify by explaining the logic of the statements following the question ,